# increase Unit dac

Tags: microcontroller

I would like to create a 16 bit DAC in STM32F103RET6. ButSTM32F103RET6 only has 12 bit DAC. How do I implement a higher resolution DAC in STM32F103RET6?
Thank you. Please see link below
[enter link description here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwirsPi8r43MAhUDOJoKHdXJAqoQFggoMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cypress.com%2Ffile%2F136326%2Fdownload&usg=AFQjCNGMTYfBJtqGyTpFVwAPRUurSabTYg&sig2=kmZVVSw8sK1GryLJgSaAhQ&bvm=bv.119408272,d.bGs)

Comment: Just add an external DAC IC that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The techniques described by Cypress in that application note are specific to the PSoC hardware, and cannot be implemented in a STM32 microcontroller.

Specifically:

- Two out of the four techniques described (PIDAC and MIDAC) require the PSoC DAC to be configured as a current output DAC (iDAC). This mode does not exist in the STM32.
- The PIDAC technique also requires the two DACs to be set to significantly different output ranges. The DACs in the STM32 are always referenced to Vref, and cannot be scaled.
- The ADC feedback technique depends on the presence of a 20-bit DAC in the PSoC. The STM32 DAC is 12-bit, making it unsuitable for this use.